# SharePoint 2016 Source URL redirection

Tags: 2016, redirect

In SharePoint 2016 on Edit form after save event, I want to redirect to external Page(like google.com, bing.com). I was trying to use the Source Parameter to do that but unfortunately it is not redirecting to the expected URL rather goes to the List Default View.

**Findings:**
Source Parameter works fine if we give the URL with same host header/web Application.

Is there any fix for this? or Is this the default behavior in SP2016?

Answer (score 1):

the source parameter can only be used to redirect to an internal site Collecection Location

if you want to redirect externally i would recommend to redirect wiki page and add a web part in that page to redirect the user to your final destination.

Comment: Thanks Erin. I hope this is not the case in SP2013, the Source parameter can be used to redirect even to external sites. Why is this changed, is there any explanation from Microsoft?

Comment: SharePoint Online is not "SharePoint 2013". Is it possible to set external source adresses on SharePoint 2016 on premises?

Comment: Am not writing about SharePoint Online, the query is about SharePoint On premises. It is not working in SP 2016 on prem but it was working with SP 2013 On prem. That is the confusion here.